# Can't run .exe files using exec() in PHP

Tags: php, c++, exe

I'm trying to use an .exe file to perform calculations and pass the output into PHP. I made a Hello World .exe file using C++, but I can't get PHP to execute it.

If I run this command from the CMD, I get the correct output:

```
C:\path\file.exe
```

But if I do this in PHP, the output is an empty string:

```
exec('C:\path\file.exe',$out);
var_dump($out);
```

But this displays the correct output:

```
exec('ipconfig',$out);
var_dump($out);
```

I'm using WAMP on Windows 7.

Edit: Here is the C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure the webserver has execute access to the file in question.

Comment: Is the server looking in the right directory? Try checking `file_exists($file)`, if not you may need to change directories/add the file to your path

Comment: @Linksku There have been several answers to this question since you posted the bounty, and you haven't commented on any of them. Have none of them been of any help to you?

Comment: @james: I was without internet connection for a week, I still currently have very limited connection. I will try out the suggestions and select a best answer if one of them works.

Comment: @Linksku That's ok. I was just prompting you because the bounty period was coming to an end. It's not urgent anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few advices that may help:

1. Use `/` instead, it also work under windows.
2. If your path contain spaces, wrap it in double quotes `$exec = '"C:/my path/file.exe"';`
3. Parameters should be passed outside double quotes `$exec = '"C:/my path/file.exe" /help';`
4. Make sure that your program actually writes to STDOUT, not STDERR.

Comment: #4 sounds like the culprit to me.

Comment: I'm a complete beginner in C++, how do I tell if I'm using STDOUT or STDERR? I added the full C++ program to the end of the post.

Comment: it's writing to stdout (cout)

Comment: How dp i know if its STDOUT or STDEER ?? @dev-null-dweller

Answer (score 6):

In a single-quoted string, you still need to escape backslashes, so to get `\` you need `\\`:

```
exec('C:\\path\\file.exe',$out);
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this. I changed it, but it's still an empty string.

Comment: No errors. I just tried opening Chrome and Photoshop using PHP, neither opened.

Comment: Those are GUI apps. Try starting them detached with "start ..." (try a simple one: "start winver.exe").

Comment: While it is certainly good practice to escape backslashes in single quoted strings it is not actually needed in specific example.

Comment: "start winver.exe" does not work either. Is there a PHP setting that prevents "exec" from running .exe files? I couldn't find anything like that in php.ini

Answer (score 3):

Use the *return_var* parameter to check the return value from the command.

```
$return = -1;
exec('C:\path\file.exe',$out,$return);
echo "Return value: $return\n";
var_dump($out);
```

In your case, if it was executed successfully it should return 0. If the file was not found, it will probably return 1. If my suspicions are correct, though, I think the most likely return value is -1073741515.

Error -1073741515 (0xc0000135) is what is returned when your application has missing DLLs. This would happen if you are using the DLL version of your compiler's run-time library.

The app may work OK when run locally, where you have the DLLs installed, but might still fail when run from your web server, which won't necessarily have them.

If this is the problem, either you need to recompile your app to use static libraries, or install the necessary DLLs on the web server. You don't say what compiler you are using, but for more information on the DLLs used by Visual C++, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I got -1073741515 (0xc0000135) when I run exec in php，my c++ program is very simple, just prints hello world, I use g++ to compile it on windows 7 and it can be called in cmd. What dll do I need in this condition?

Answer (score 2):

Check your config/php.ini file, exec function could be disbaled under **disable_functions** or check the line **open_basedir**, PHP could be limited to access certain directories

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your code to test it and:

The first time I get not output.

I added the file_exists test and get:

```
Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(xxxxxxxxx) is not within the allowed path(s): (xxxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xxx:) 
in xxxxxx/test.php on line 4 
Call Stack: 0.0004 645640 1. {main}() xxxx/test.php:0 0.0004 646016 2. 
file_exists() xxxxxx/test.php:4
```

I moved file.exe to the same directory of test.php and get:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Hello World" }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$file = 'xxxxx/file.exe';
if (!file_exists($file)) echo 'File does not exists';
exec($file, $out);
var_dump($out);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
exec('"C:\\folder name with space\\program.exe" argument1 "argument2 with space"', $output, $return);
var_dump($output); //"Hello World"
var_dump($return); //0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can create a `test.bat` file and enter(`fwrite()`) the command in it. Then execute(`exec('test.bat', $out, $ret)`) that bat file.

`test.bat` contains:

```
C:\path\file.exe
```