# Start a program from PHP

Tags: php, cmd, executable

I'm trying to do this:
`system("cmd /c C:\test.txt");`
I already tried `exec("C:\test.txt")`, `exec('"C:\test.txt"')`, but nothing is working, some tries the script only keeps loading and some tries he loads but no returns! I'm thinking that is permissions problem..

Comment: First... why?  Second, what are you wanting to do with the file?  There are a lot of functions to work within files for php, why do you need the command line to do it?

Comment: `.txt` files aren't typically runnable programs. What does it contain? What is the supposed outcome?

Comment: `exec('"C:\test.txt"')` will not work because `test.txt` is not an executable. you should specify an executable file and pass `test.txt` to it as a parameter.

Comment: It's just a example, actually I want to run a batch file..

Answer (score 4):

You can create a .bat file and use this:

**openfile.bat**

```
start notepad "myfile.txt"
"myshortcut.lnk"
exit
```

**PHP**

```
exec("C:\openfile.bat")
```

Source: [Open text file and program shortcut in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657777/open-text-file-and-program-shortcut-in-windows-batch-file)

**EDIT**
Unfortunately i cant test this right now but if you want the process to run in the background this might do the trick in both windows and linux:

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
} 

execInBackground(start /B openfile.bat);
```

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

also try:

```
exec("start /B C:\openfile.bat");
```

and I found an other stack question regaring the same: [How do you run a .bat file from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835941/how-do-you-run-a-bat-file-from-php)

Comment: Didn't work! :x, I want to RUN, EXECUTE a .exe, not in background.. that just doesn't do anothing, I was thinking about use COM or something.. 'cause this can be a permission apache error

Comment: Maybe the problem is how you write your filename. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458610/cant-run-exe-files-using-exec-in-php